# Unit testing in the UI layer

Tags: unit-testing

I'm looking for advice on how/to what extent our UI should be unit tested.

We create appliances which are deployed to clients. Each appliance consists of 4 physical servers running various virtual servers. We've got components written in Java, Python, .Net, PHP and even some PERL which we haven't managed to get rid of yet.

All of these components are managed by an API which in turn exposes a webservice to the UI.

The UI is a Python/Django (MVC) website which largely proxies Ajax requests from the views to the Api and handles some things like sessions/auth tokens.

Most of the controller methods are very noddy, something like this...

```
def Search(request):
    try:
        Request = {'Terms': request.REQUEST.get('Terms', '')}
        Data = ApiHelper.Get('Search', Request)
        return HttpResponse(JsonLib().encode(Data), content_type='application/json')
    except HTTPError as Ex:
        return ExceptionHandler.Handle(request, Ex)
```

Since the API is being unit tested, I'm unconvinced that the UIs controller methods should be unit tested (or even what they should be tested for?).

What's the "correct" approach here? Testing that each of the hundreds of methods invokes the exception handler correctly? 99% of them are carbon copies. (Saying that makes me think it's not DRY but I can't see a nicer way to do it since parameters/api calls vary).